# PyInstaller Runtime Error? (R6034)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've finally gotten PyInstaller to build an exe file, but it's not running. As soon as I open it, I get this in a dialog:

```
Runtime Error!
Program C:\.....\MCManager.exe

R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Here's my spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['MCManager.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Dropbox'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'MCManager.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          icon='MCManager.ico')
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name=os.path.join('dist', 'MCManager.exe.app'))
```

I've looked around, and nobody seems to have this same problem.

If it changes things at all, this script uses wxPython.

Comment: I had the same issue with pyinstaller 3.2 and python 2.7.11. Getting back to pyinstaller 3.1 resolved the problem :)

Answer (score 10):

I was going to leave a comment, but not enough rep. Though this was asked awhile ago I recently ran into the same issue and it turned out to be a Pyinstaller bug with version 3.2.

Resulting exe terminates with R6034 after upgrade to pyinstaller 3.2:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1985

PyInstaller 3.2, OneFile R6034, 32-bit Python 2.7.11
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2042

Looks like they've fixed this in the latest dev version and it's suggested to

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Using this in my requirements file instead of pyinstaller==3.2 patched it for me!

Comment: This worked for me so in some cases at least it is the right answer!

Comment: Right answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

I recently started getting "Runtime Error? (R6034)"
It was on a solid existing python program which I had used pyinstaller before to compile to a onefile.  I noticed that the problem only happened after I renamed the exe after it had been compiled.  Once I renamed it back to the original exe name, the R6034 went away.

Leason learned... don't rename your exe after building with pyinstaller.  If you need your exe to have a different name, then change the source py name and then recompile.

Comment: This was the cause of my R6034 woes after switching from PyInstaller 2.1 to 3.4.  It is, in fact perfectly fine to rename the exe, but when you do that you need to also rename the MANIFEST!  P.i. generates a manifest for you to resolve the VC redistributal dll loading at run time.  Windows requires the exe and the manifest to share a base name for them to be associated and the manifest respected.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be similar problem https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/689

See if you can use that workaround:

> I was able to fix the problem by building the executable using the
>   onedir option instead of onefile, then simply moving just the manifest
>   to the directory containing the single-file executable, which allowed
>   it to work.

Seems they're fixing it in 3.0

Comment: I have the same issue now and using onedir works for me too. However I am on the developer release of pyinstaller so it does not seem to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, not renaming anything, I just build the -F and crash with version 3.2 however this error don't appear with version 2.1 .

Link:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases/download/v2.1/PyInstaller-2.1.zip

My advise? pip uninstall pyinstaller
after that you should install version 2.1 and you are ready to run again.
./setup.py build
./setup.py install

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you call popen within a pyinstaller built exe.  To fix this error you must use an explicit file handle for stdout of the popen call like the following example.

```
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def verify_license():
    tmp_file = '.license_output'

    try:
        with open(tmp_file, 'w+') as file_obj:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hi'], shell=True,
                                    stdout=file_obj, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            ret = proc.wait()

        if ret != 0:
            sys.exit(-1)

        with open(tmp_file, 'r') as file_obj:
            output = file_obj.read()

    except Exception as err:
        sys.exit(-1)

    if 'hi' not in output:
        raise Exception('bad news: output was %s' % (output))


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    verify_license()
    main()
```